# Hough Line gives negative rhos

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to generate some Hough Lines using `HoughLines()`,l but some of the lines have negative `rho` values like:

`array([[-58.,   3.07177949]], dtype=float32))`

`array([[-56.,   3.05432606]], dtype=float32))`

Since `rho = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`, how come `rho` can ever be negative? Is the origin the centre of the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rho` is not `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`. It is the offset of the line from the origin, positive if on one side and negative if on the other. From the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), the general expression of the line is:

`rho= x*cos(theta) + y*sin(theta)`

Comment: To expand a bit more, `theta` is in `[0, pi)`, so `rho` can be negative, which corresponds to the additional angles from `[pi, 2*pi)`. If you're implementing the Hough transform yourself, you have a choice on whether to use that parameterization, OR, you could use angles in `[0, 2*pi)` and only positive `rho` values. However OpenCV uses `theta` in `[0, pi)` as seen in the [docs for `HoughLines()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghlines): **max_theta** ... Must fall between `min_theta` and `CV_PI`.

Comment: Is the origin the centre of the image though?

Comment: @JohnM. You probably figured it out by now, but the origin point (0,0) in an OpenCV image is the upper-left corner of the image.  The positive X axis goes to the right, and the positive Y axis goes downwards. This is counter-intuitive to the math world (where the positive Y axis typically goes upwards), but normal for computer graphics.